# converting arabic words to windows-1252

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, arabic, windows-1252

I'm inserting large amount of data to a oracle database.

In that database text is stored in windows-1252 format.

It turns out that there are lot of things to be entered, all of them need to be converted to this format. Also all of those data is in Arabic words.

can some one help me to find a online converter or a tool that encodes Arabic words to windows-1252 format?

*hope the details are enough

--rangana

Comment: The Windows-1252 code page is incapable of representing Arabic text.  Its repertoire only covers a set of Latin characters.  If you want to store Arabic, you need to use an encoding which can accommodate all the character data you want to store.  These days, a sane default would be Unicode.  Before there was Unicode, people would have come up with some ugly workaround, like wrapping the Arabic bytes in a container of some sort, perhaps à la RFC2047.  But go with Unicode, it was devised precisely to solve issues like this.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: i'd rather ask for more info about the server side of your application , i can help with more accurate answer , this is online converter http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php

Comment: Windows-1252 may not be intended to encode Arabic script, but it can; don't ask me how.  But this page: https://www.cia.gov/library/abbottabad-compound/Documents.20171105.hash_index.txt  will display as gibberish unless you treat it as Windows-1252.  For example, copy-paste a line from that page over to here: https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx , and then tell it to encode with Window-1252 and decode with UTF-8.  Presto, Arabic letters!  (You can also look at the page in Firefox, and tell it View | Repair Text Encoding.  Then use Firefox's Page Info to display the char encoding.)

Comment: Mike Maxwell, your example shows nothing of the kind. What Firefox does is a guess on the actual encoding of the data, as a stream of bytes, ignoring any specified or implied encoding.

What happens in Firefox, and in the tool you mention, is that the bytes are interpreted as utf-8 data. Windows-1252, or any other specific 8-bit enooding. is not relevant here at all.

Answer (score 1):

The pair of Win32 APIs, MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte, allow you to convert code-page encoding to Unicode and Unicode data to code-page encoding, respectively. Each of these APIs takes as an argument the value of the code page to be used for that conversion. You can, therefore, either specify the value of a given code page (example: 1256 for Arabic) or use predefined flags such as:

- CP_ACP: for the currently selected system Windows code page
- CP_OEMCP:  for the currently selected system OEM code page
- CP_UTF8: for conversions between UTF-16 and UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Since windows-1252 does not encode Arabic letters at all, the only way to do the conversion would be to use some kind of transliteration. This is something completely different from encoding conversion (which does not change the identity of characters, only their coded representation).

There is a large number of transliteration (romanization) schemes for Arabic. Almost all of them non-reversible, and almost all of them not suitable for fully automatic processing (mainly because normal Arabic writing does not indicate short vowels but most transliteration schemes indicate them, i.e. the transliterator needs to know how the word is pronounced and to insert vowel characters).

You could fake a conversion by converting to windows-1256 and then inserting the windows-1256 encoded data into the database as raw bytes. You would then need to keep track of the encoding of each value in the database, so that you know which bytes are windows-1252 and which are really windows-1256. This sounds like a mess, so consider whether it is possible to convert the data base to use UTF-8.

Comment: Actually, Win-1252 apparently can encode Arabic letters, see my comment above.

Comment: Mike Maxwell, you are commenting on my answer with a reference to your comment on the question. This is not appropriate. If you have an answer, please provide it. If you want to comment on an answer, please address the answer directly.